# Multiple Lists in One object

Tags: c#, list, aggregate

I have 3 Lists `List<A>` ,`List<B>`,`List<C>` in `C#` all the List types are CUSTOM types and NOT same types. I am looking for a type where I could add all the 3 lists and pass on to jQuery and where I could iterate the big object (mix of all three lists).

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the type of List you use? List<int>, List<double>, List<T>,....? When you say you want to pass them to Jquery, how you are going to achieve this?

Comment: all my lists are of Custom types. I want to call a web method from Jquery that will return the big object.

Comment: Do you want a collection with elements from all three lists inside of it? Or do you want a structure with three branches? You are not very specific in your question.

Comment: I want a collection but still want to keep all the sub collection separate. So I could do like myObject.TypeA[0].ElementA and myObject.TypeB[0].ElementC something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be a `Tuple`:

```
var tuple = Tuple.Create(listA, listB, listC);
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking

```
[WebMethod]
public List<IList> GetList()
{
    List<IList> list = new List<IList>();

    list.Add(list1);
    list.Add(list2);
    list.Add(list3);

    return list;
}
```

Another approach would be:

```
[WebMethod]
public List<object> GetList()
{
    List<object> list = new List<object>();

    list.Add(list1);
    list.Add(list2);
    list.Add(list3);

    return list;
}
```

The method GetList() will reside in your web service class.

Comment: I think in your example, list1,list2,list3 are all of SAME type? isn't it. But I am looking for 3 different types of lists

Comment: Yeah, they are all of the same type. Give me few minutes to change it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyList

{
   List <MyList> List { get; set; };

    public   List <MyList> AddList(List<Mylist> List1,List<MyList> List2)
  {
     List1.AddRange(List2).ToList();
     return List1;
  }
}
```